# Center Aligning an SVG element?

Tags: svg, path

I don't know how to really explain this but how can I center align this logo

http://jsfiddle.net/fa7w3h99/3/

I have tried the following but it didnt seem to work as intended.

```
.center-logo {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change the `width`, `height`, and `viewbox` attributes of your svg.

Here I'd say it should be :
`width="135px" height="135px" viewBox="0 0 135 135"`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fa7w3h99/5/)

Comment: Oh and unrelated but you must not have same id used multiple times in the same document